# Groovy compare string

Tags: groovy

I have the Groovy code as below

```
def retVal = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl ${URI}; echo \$?")

println("Return value: ${retVal}") -> it printed 0

if (retVal == "0") {

    println("Successfull") -> it doesn't go here

}
```

why the above condition can't be catched?

Comment: I tried with (retVal == 0) but still don't work

Comment: actually retVal is String. retVal.trim() == "0" will work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to be using the Jenkins API incorrectly.

If all you need is the exit code of the process, use `returnStatus: true`:

```
def retVal = sh(returnStatus: true, script: "curl ${URI}")
if (retVal == 0) {
    println 'success'
} else {
    println "Something wrong, exit code was $retVal")
}
```

Now, if you really want the stdout instead, perhaps clean up the String first by calling `trim()` on it or try to match the String against a regex:

```
if (retValue ~== /\s*0\s*/) {
    println "success"
} else {
    println "Something wrong, exit code was '$retVal'")
}
```

I always put quotes around a value I print to make sure new-lines or whitespaces don't make me waste time with bad values.